# How to repair a polygon with self-intersection?

Tags: geometry, intersection, geos

Is there a way to remove self-intersections from a polygon using GEOS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, I have to answer the question myself. Maybe it will help someone.

You can repair a polygon using the geos::operation::buffer::BufferOp class. E.g.

```
geos::geom::Geometry * result = 
                       geos::operation::buffer::BufferOp::bufferOp(polygon, 1.0);
```

You can find some more good recipes in the [Secrets of the JTS Topology Suite.](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/files/jts_secrets_foss4g2007.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Often point intersections are allowed, so you can change

```
1  2   4
*--*   *       
|   \ /|
|    X |
|   / \|
*--*   *
6  5   3
```

to

```
1  2   4
*--*   *       
|   \ /|
|   3*6|
|   / \|
*--*   *
8  7   5
```

where points 3 and 6 are the same. If point intersections are not allowed, move one of them a small amount.

In my experience, most such intersections some from a faulty polygon simplification, so it would be better to go back to the source if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Self-intersected polygon is invalid. Thus BufferOp may give invalid result.
I didn't find any way to fix self-intersected polygon in geos.
st_makevalid function in PostGIS uses geos. So it is possible to investigate the source code.

Comment: It's worth to clarify that "self-intersecting polygon is invalid" but according to OGC SFS. It is a valid complex polygon in the world of geometry.